# How to use UIApplication and openURL and call a swift function on "string" from foo://q=string?

Tags: ios, swift, ios8

I would like my swift iOS app to call a function on a custom url's query. I have a url like this `myApp://q=string`. I would like to launch my app and call a function on `string`. I have already registered the url in Xcode and my app launches by typing `myApp://` in the Safari address bar. This is what I have so far in my AppDelegate.swift:

```
func application(application: UIApplication!, openURL url: NSURL!, sourceApplication: String!, annotation: AnyObject!) -> Bool {


    return true
}
```

How do I get the query `string` so I can call `myfunction(string)`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your URL

```
myApp://q=string
```

does not conform to the [RFC 1808 "Relative Uniform Resource Locators"](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1808). The general form of an URL is

```
<scheme>://<net_loc>/<path>;<params>?<query>#<fragment>
```

which in your case would be

```
myApp://?q=string
```

where the question mark starts the query part of the URL. With *that* URL,
you can use the `NSURLComponents` class to extract the various parts such
as the query string and its items:

```
if let urlComponents = NSURLComponents(URL: url, resolvingAgainstBaseURL: false) {
    if let queryItems = urlComponents.queryItems as? [NSURLQueryItem]{
        for queryItem in queryItems {
            if queryItem.name == "q" {
                if let value = queryItem.value {
                    myfunction(value)
                    break
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The `NSURLComponents` class is available on iOS 8.0 and later.

*Note:* In the case of your simple URL you *could* extract the value of the query
parameter directly using simple string methods:

```
if let string = url.absoluteString {
    if let range = string.rangeOfString("q=") {
        let value = string[range.endIndex ..< string.endIndex]
        myFunction(value)
    }
}
```

But using `NSURLComponents` is less error-prone and more flexible if you decide
to add more query parameters later.